# Figuring out 3d slide's width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement this [3D slide](http://lorcho.stoutwebtech.com/UnitedWeStand/demo-2.html) from the iDangerous Swiper. I could not figure where the width and height of the div class=swiper-slide come from. Below is the body body:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/2.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/sliders/moover/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/4.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/sliders/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/3.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/sliders/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/5.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/sliders/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/7.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/cs/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(images/6.jpg)">
                <a href="http://www.idangero.us/sliders/s6/" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        slidesPerView:3,
        loop:true,
        //Enable 3D Flow
        tdFlow: {
            rotate : 30,
            stretch :10,
            depth: 150,
            modifier : 1,
            shadows:true
        }
    })
    </script>
```

When I use firebug to look at the height and width, I could not find where the `height: 189px;` and `width: 293.333px;` came from. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It likely comes from the js. Got a link to it?

Comment: The only two scripts it use are:

<script src="scripts/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js"></script>

Links are:
http://lorcho.stoutwebtech.com/UnitedWeStand/scripts/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js
http://lorcho.stoutwebtech.com/UnitedWeStand/scripts/idangerous.swiper.3dflow-2.0.js

I got the scripts from this site.

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/3dflow.php

Comment: The only thing I can see is in the minified js so it's hard to tell. Go to the minified js and search for "width=" and you can see that `i` and `e` are the only things with their width set in js, so it's likely one of those